Python3.11 handle HttpException raised alongwith the status code
I see one of the methods in python uses raise_for_status():
        def raise_for_status(self):
        
            if 400 <= self.status_code < 500:
                http_error_msg = (
                  f"{self.status_code} Client Error: {reason} for url: {self.url}"
                )

            elif 500 <= self.status_code < 600:
                http_error_msg = (
                   f"{self.status_code} Server Error: {reason} for url: {self.url}"
                )
        
            if http_error_msg:
                raise self.status_code, HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)

I want to add a try/except block such that, I can handle the exception. However, it also raises the status code along with the exception.
Not sure, how can I capture the status code without modifying the existing code for rasei_for_status()

It sounds like you want the status code but not the exception. If this is the case, just get the status code from the Response object: response.status_code. You don't need to call raise_for_status() in order to get the status code.

There is property Response.status_code in the response. You can do:
import requests

url = "https://www.google.com/nonexistent_path"

try:
    r = requests.get(url)
    r.raise_for_status()
except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as err:
    print("Status code:", r.status_code)
    print("Error:", err)

Prints:
Status code: 404
Error: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://www.google.com/nonexistent_path

